# How to create cover-flow with swiftui without using external api

Tags: swiftui, tabview, coverflow

How I could create a Cover flow with SwiftUI TabView without using any external dependency.

Like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVze9.png)

```
     TabView(selection: self.$pg.index){
        ForEach(0 ..< 5) {item in
            FruitCardView(fruit: fruitsData[item])
        }
        
    }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.leading)
    .padding(.vertical, 20)
```

How I want to display it :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb8GN.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tabview.

```
TabView {
    ForEach(pages) { page in
        Text(page.name)
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview

Comment: I want to show multiple pages like the photo I attached, 
So the user could see the previous and next pages.
Tabview For paging fills the screen.
Is it doable with TabView ?

Comment: @youssefmyh Yes you can, put the view inside the forach like this(updated my answer).

Comment: still not working still the TabView showing single page per screen.

Comment: @youssefmyh can you update your post with code?

Comment: Code updated,
I looking to displaying multiple views on the same page and zoom on the selected view. Cover-Flow
Like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb8GN.png

Comment: Such a animation is sadly not possible with `Tabview()`
You have to customise yourself or you can use library from someone.
I recommend to you this git repo: https://github.com/amirdew/CollectionViewPagingLayout

Comment: it seems yea it's not possible with TabView, Thanks